# What are the best free(ware?) PC performance benchmarking options out there?

Tags: windows, performance, benchmarking

I'd like to get a rough idea on the performance of my machines, so quite simply: what would you guys recommend as decent, free benchmarking software?

Please specify whether your suggestions are good for desktop performance benchmarking, gaming, or multimedia processing (or any other benchmarking "areas" I've forgotten about since my last encounter with this field). I'm interested in testing all areas.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.futuremark.com/ 3dMark and PcMark.

They are the makers of some of the most commonly used benchmark tools for 3d performance and CPU speed.  I commonly see reviews reference there tests all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Vista Experience score is free, comes with Vista and Win 7, and benchmarks several different components.

Answer (score 2):

PC Wizard 2009, Fresh Diagnosis, and SIW are the best ones I have seen, I personally like SIW and PC Wizard as freeware...

Answer (score 2):

I've already posted about this once today but what the hell...

## [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/)

[image]

The Phoronix Test Suite is the most comprehensive testing and benchmarking platform available for the Linux operating system. This software is designed to effectively carry out both qualitative and quantitative benchmarks in a clean, reproducible, and easy-to-use manner. This software is based upon the extensive Linux benchmarking work and internal tools developed by Phoronix.com since 2004 along with input from leading tier-one computer hardware vendors. This software is open-source and licensed under the GNU GPLv3. The Phoronix Test Suite consists of a lightweight processing core (pts-core) with each benchmark consisting of an XML-based profile with related resource scripts. The process from the benchmark installation, to the actual benchmarking, to the parsing of important hardware and software components is heavily automated and completely repeatable, asking users only for confirmation of actions.

- 100+ Test Profiles
- 40+ Test Suites
- Extensible (XML-based) Testing Architecture
- **Optional Linux-based LiveDVD/USB Testing Distribution (PTS Desktop Live)**
- Automated Test Installation
- Dependency Management Support
- Module-based Plug-In Architecture
- Integrated Results Viewer
- PNG, JPG, Adobe SWF, SVG Graph Rendering Support
- Autonomous Batch Mode Support
- Global Database For Result Uploads, Benchmark Comparisons
- HTML Documentation Covering Test Profiles, Module Framework
- Installed Software, Hardware Detection
- System Monitoring Support
- Runs On Linux, OpenSolaris, Mac OS X, & BSD Operating Systems

Comment: Riiiiiight, and it says that where in the original question?

Comment: Just noticed the tag, the poster should have made it clear that they wanted _ONLY_ windows benchmarking software tbh. Also the tag could have been added after the question was posted ;)

Answer (score 1):

One I've used before is SiSoftware's Sandra **Lite**, which is the free but less-featured version of their commercial product.  In addition to providing some benchmarks, it can also gather information about your hardware, etc.

> "SiSoftware Sandra (the System
>   ANalyser, Diagnostic and Reporting
>   Assistant) is an information &
>   diagnostic utility. It should provide
>   most of the information (including
>   undocumented) you need to know about
>   your hardware, software and other
>   devices whether hardware or software.
>   [...]"

Here's [the download page](http://www.sisoftware.net/index.html?dir=dload&location=sware_dl_all&langx=en&a=).

Answer (score 1):

A little off topic, but using FurMark for 3D benchmarks is a total win.

Comment: I won't to know what Fur has to do with benchmarking ;)

Answer (score 0):

Everest would be a good gaming benchmark tool.