# What options do I have for benchmarking software?

Tags: windows, benchmarking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best free(ware?) PC performance benchmarking options out there?](https://superuser.com/questions/22997/what-are-the-best-freeware-pc-performance-benchmarking-options-out-there)

Can anyone tell me some benchmark software for Windows? I'm using **PassMark PerformanceTest** & **PCMark**. I'm also looking for a stress software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the software I use include [3D Mark 06](http://www.futuremark.com/benchmarks/3dmark06/introduction/), [SuperPI](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=36), [wPrime](http://www.wprime.net/), [SiSoft Sandra](http://www.sisoftware.net/)

For stress testing, [OCCT](http://www.overclock.net/downloads/191765-occt.html), [Orthos](http://www.overclock.net/downloads/138142-orthos.html) & [Prime95](http://www.overclock.net/downloads/137251-prime95.html) are good choices.

Related: 2D/3D Benchmarking software [list thread on Overclock.net](http://www.overclock.net/benchmarking-software-discussion/485683-2d-3d-benchmarking-stability-software-list.html)

Answer (score 3):

besides passmark and pcmark, i'm using **[GeekBench](http://www.primatelabs.ca/geekbench/)** for processor benchmarking, **[ATTO Disk Benchmark](http://downloads.guru3d.com/ATTO-Disk-Benchmark-v2.41-download-2343.html)** for hard drive and SSD performance checks.

if you need a stress tester, get **[Intel BurnTest](http://downloads.guru3d.com/IntelBurnTest-v2.3-download-2047.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

I like SiSoft Sandra because there is some reference scores included for comparing hardware.  Of course you should realize that those reference scores were probably collected on a totally different system than yours, but it is good for getting a rough idea of performance differences if you are thinking about an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

on linux it is phoronix test suite. It makes a lot of different workloads available and there is also a life CD image

Answer (score 0):

My Weapon of Choice is [IOMETER](http://www.iometer.org/).  It is used to test the HDD at the Block Level.