# What can I use to benchmark my PC that is free?

Tags: benchmarking

I'd like to benchmark my system before and after I upgrade some hardware and quantify the performance improvements made.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/22997/what-are-the-best-freeware-pc-performance-benchmarking-options-out-there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try: [PassMark PerformanceTest](http://www.passmark.com/products/pt.htm). It tests all aspects of your computer including CPU,Hard Drive, RAM, GPU, Network, and Disk Drive. Displays detailed results. Free trial.

Comment: very nice they have a 64bit version also

Answer (score 2):

[PCMark](http://www.futuremark.com/benchmarks/pcmarkvantage/download/) (the free edition) from me same maker of 3DMark is a famous PC benchmarking tool. It should meet your requirements.

Comment: PCMark has been moved to a new URL: https://benchmarks.ul.com/pcmark10 . The free edition seems to require a Steam account now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [NovaBench](http://novabench.com/)... Free to try !